# How can find out how much memory a game or DLC will require?

Tags: xbox-360

I was thinking about buying an xbox 360 for Christmas, but I'm not sure how large of a hard drive I should get. I was looking at the 4GB one,  but I'm worried it won't be large enough for the games I want to play. How can I find out how much memory is required to play the games I want, whether it be a digital or physical copy?  I'm wondering the same about the individual DLC as well.

Comment: In it's current form this question really isn't a good fit for our site. We don't answer shopping recommendation questions here, which is what this currently is. Your question regarding how much hard drive you require is unanswerable as well. We can't really you how much hard drive you're going to need, and even if we could, it's too specific of a focus (we like questions to be useful to future visitors to the site, not just the asker).

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question to instead ask *how* you can find out how much space various games and DLC take up. That way you can figure out the answer to "How much space will I need?" yourself, and will allow future visitors to the site to do the same.

Comment: Thanks for touching up your question! Your edits fixed my concerns, and I fixed it up a little bit more myself to make your question a bit more focused and clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Out-of-the-box, the 4GB Xbox 360 is the same in every regard save one: it's hard drive space.  The main hardware (CPU, GPU and RAM) of the different bundles is *exactly the same*.  That being said, the answer to your question is, "yes".

Comment: The question has been edited since you've answered it, but one of the games he mentioned was Battlefield 4, which won't work on a 4GB XBOX: [source](http://www.gamefront.com/ea-battlefield-4-will-not-work-on-4gb-xbox-360-s/)